# add parameter to ng-click in angular

Tags: angular

How can I add the cart.id to a `(click)="onRemove()"` method and use it in that fuction?

```
onRemoveProduct() {
    this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
        this.mhttp.deleteFromCart(params.get('id')))
    )
      .subscribe((response: any) => {
        this.product = response;
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just pass it as a parameter

```
(click)="onRemove(cart.id)" 

onRemoveProduct(cartId: string) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    tap((params: ParamMap) => this.cartId = params.get('id')),
    switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.mhttp.deleteFromCart(params.get('id')))
  .subscribe((response: any) => {
    this.product = response;
  });
}

onRemove() {
  if (this.cartId) {
    console.log(this.cartId);
    console.log(this.product);
  } else {
    console.log('observable has not fired yet');
  }
}
```

Then just access it anywhere in your template (`cartId`) or .ts file (`this.cartId`) - e.g.

Here's a suitable click handler ... `(click)="onRemove()"`

Comment: What is `params`?

Comment: My point is, it won't work before calling `onRemoveProduct`. You cannot just add that line and magically expect it to work.